# SaveAccount not work in Xamarin.Auth

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, keystore, keychain, xamarin.auth

I use `Xamarin.Auth` to save account to make "Remember me" function in my `Xamarin.Forms` project.
It works good for both Android and iOS in debug mode.
But when I build it in release mode, it doesn't work for both platforms.

I can't find what is the problem and how I can fix it.
Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Xamarin.Auth are you using? Start with downloading latest version of Xamarin.Auth and it's source code from gitHub.

Comment: I added it from NuGet and its version is 1.5.0.3

Comment: Download and attach the source code, you will be able to track down the problem with custom milestones at least.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I figured out that the issue was with the Linking property in Android and iOS. My linking property was set to 'None' for both debug and release. It worked fine in debug but on release I had to change it to 'SDK Assemblies Only' and it worked perfectly fine after changing. Just note that changing these properties can have negative effect in your app so test everything thoroughly. I suggest for you to read the links below to understand what linking is doing.

[Android Linking Property](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/)

[iOS Linker Property](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/linker/)

Comment: My linking property set to 'None' for both debug and release. I've tried to change linking property to 'SDK Assemblies Only'. But it failed to build.

Comment: @Passionate.C can you post your code? Most of the time when an app works in debug mode but not in release it has to do with the linker property but in your case there may be something else. Double check you give your app the correct permissions on iOS and Android for access to Account Store. I would think you do have the right permissions since it's running on iOS in debug, but double check just in case.